# Proving $\frac{(a+|a|)^2}{4} + \frac{(a-|a|)^2}{4}=a^2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Whats need to be proven, let $b\neq 0$

$$\frac{(a+|a|)^2}{4} + \frac{(a-|a|)^2}{4}=a^2$$

That's what I tried:
$$\frac{(a+|a|)^2}{4} + \frac{(a-|a|)^2}{4}=a^2$$

$${(a+|a|)}^2 + {(a-|a|)^2}=4a^2$$
$${(a^2+|a|^2+2a|a|)} + {(a^2+|a|^2-2a|a|)}=4a^2$$
$${2a^2+2|a|^2}=4a^2$$

I'm not even sure the first transition I made is correct. Thanks

Comment: Looks good to me. Now, for the last part, notice that for real numbers, $|a|^2 = a^2$ (both are always non-negative).

Comment: What is $b\neq 0$?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.
An alternate way.

First let $a\ge 0 \Rightarrow |a| = a$.

> So, $\left(\dfrac{a+|a|}{2}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{a-|a|}{2}\right)^2 = \left(\dfrac{a+a}{2}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{a-a}{2}\right)^2  = a^2$

Similarly, $a<0 \Rightarrow |a| = -a$

> So, $\left(\dfrac{a+|a|}{2}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{a-|a|}{2}\right)^2 = \left(\dfrac{a-a}{2}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{a+a}{2}\right)^2  = a^2$

Answer (score 0):

Your manipualtion doesn't involve any critical step which requires attention or additional condition.

Indeed for any $C \neq 0$ the following step

$$\frac A C = \frac B C \iff C\cdot \frac A C = C\cdot \frac B C \iff A=B$$

is always allowed and so also for the following steps, indeed for any $A,B$ the identity

$$(A+B)^2=A^2+2AB+B^2$$

always holds.

Finally we can conclude, from your final step as follows

$${2a^2+2|a|^2}=4a^2 \iff 2|a|^2=4a^2-2a^2 \iff 2|a|^2=2a^2 \iff |a|^2=a^2$$

which is true.